# How can I use argument of outer function in an inner function in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-filter

I am trying to build a customized filter function using `array_filter()` in php

```
    $lst = [["indexNo" => '123', "name" =>"aaa", grade => 8],
    ["indexNo" => '124', "name" =>"abc", grade => 8],
    ["indexNo" => '125', "name" =>"avb", grade => 9]
    ];
    
    function filterByIndex($grade){
            global $lst;
            return array_filter($lst, function($record){
                
                $record['grade'] == $grade;
            });
    
            
        }
```

The compiler says that the `$garde` in line(`$record['grade'] == $grade`) is not declared.

What can I do for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues. First, `$grade` is not the same as `$garde` in the function definition.  Second, use the `use()` construct to get the variable into the anonymous function.  Third, you need to `return` `true` or `false` for the filter to work:

```
function filterByIndex($grade){
        global $lst;
        return array_filter($lst, function($record) use($grade){
            return ($record['grade'] == $grade);
        });
}
```

Also, in your `$lst` definition you are using the index `garde` but in the function you use index `grade`.

Working [Demo](https://3v4l.org/dfoeV).

Comment: It works for me. actually I didn't know about use() as I am beginner for php. Thank you